# Какая правильная вложенность в media?

Tags: css3

Подскажите какая правильная вложенность медиа запросов. Все медиа написаны как min-width, но нужно добавить max-width для маленьких экранов, при добавлении в самом начале и конце, медиа запрос на max-width: 320px не работает

```
@media (max-width: 320px)  {
    .info-block4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 10%;
    }

    .first::before {
    bottom: 81px;
}


    .centr::before {
    bottom: 81px;
}   

    .last::before {
    bottom: 81px;
}


}


    @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .info-block4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 10%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px){}
```

и тд min-width: 900, 1200, 1900

Comment: добавьте Ваш код пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

@screen-xs-max, @screen-sm-min и тд. переменные из less, можете подставить свои значения с "px" например:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) { ... }
```

начинайте от максимума маленького экрана и заканчивайте размером минимум большого экрана.

Answer (score 1):

У вас используется методика Mobile First, т.е. сначала пишем все стили, которые нужны маленьким экранам, и некую часть стилей, которая будет использована для всех экранов.
Далее добавляем пошагово отображение для все более широких экранов.
Существует и обратная методика.
Окончательный выбор методики зависит от различия между требуемым отображением - где больше понадобится стилей - на смартфонах или же на планшетах-декстопах.
Но чаще такой выбор не производится, а просто-напросто верстальщик впихивает свой проверенный шаблон!!)))
Если говорить языком кода, о у вас что-то типа такого:

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px){

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px){

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px){

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px){

}
```

Я дико извиняюсь, но так и не понял, чего-же вы хотите, поэтому предположу, что вам нужно отдельным куском стилей прописать отображение для определенного диапазона экранов, нет ничего проще!!))) Ниже пример, который вы можете вставить сразу после правила min-width : 320px

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {

}
```